# pytest: assert escaped characters with re.escape() fails

Tags: python, regex, escaping, pytest

I have a function that returns characters using `re.escape()` method.
In the empirical tests it seems to work, I wanted to test it with pytest.
But I couldn't get the tests to work, so after a few attempts I tried something like that:

```
    def test_escape():
>       assert re.escape('!') == "\\!"
E       AssertionError: assert '!' == '\\!'
E         - !
E         + \!

test/test_e.py:6: AssertionError
```

I also tested it with the interpreter, who works without any problem:

```
>>> re.escape('!') == '\\!'
True
```

disabling the capturing of the output of pytest with "-s" and trying to print the output of `re.escape('!')` I get `"!"` and not `"\!"`, which does not happen on the interpreter.

I tried to monkeypatch re.escape by forcing `"\!"` as the output and it magically works. This obviously does not solve my problem but highlights some kind of problem unknown to me with re.escape

```
@pytest.fixture
def mock_escape(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr(re, "escape", lambda x: "\\!")

def test_escape(mock_escape):
    assert re.escape('!') == "\\!"
```

...

```
test/test_e.py .

======================================== 1 passed in 0.07s =========================================
all test passed
```

Just for curiosity I did the same thing with my original function (without monkeypatching but editing its return) and even in this case it works.
So it is not a problem that happens because of the import.

<strike># EDIT: #
**as tmt discovered, it's a problem with the python or pytest version.
The problem occurs with python 3.7.2 and pytest 5.2.1.
The problem does NOT occur with python 3.6.3 and pytest 4.5.0**
So it is almost certainly a bug (in my opinion more easily of pytest)</strike> 
As guy reply, it is simply a behaviour change of re.escape()

Comment: I don't get an assertion error in pytest for `assert re.escape("!") == "\\!"`. (Python 3.6.7, pytest 5.2.2)

Comment: Yes! It is true! with python3.6 everything works well, I was using 3.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [re.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/re.py) you will see `escape()` is using defined special characters list

```
_special_chars_map = {i: '\\' + chr(i) for i in b'()[]{}?*+-|^$\\.&~# \t\n\r\v\f'}

def escape(pattern):
    """
    Escape special characters in a string.
    """
    if isinstance(pattern, str):
        return pattern.translate(_special_chars_map)
    else:
        pattern = str(pattern, 'latin1')
        return pattern.translate(_special_chars_map).encode('latin1')
```

and `!` is not included there, so `re.escape('!')` return `!`, not `\!`.

```
assert re.escape('[') == '\\['
```

for example will work.

**Update**:

This answer is for Python 3.7, it works on Python 3.6. [Pull request #1007](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/1007) changed `escape()` [pull source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/5908300e4b0891fc5ab8bd24fba8fac72012eaa7#diff-daea55f2fca784d9a64ca8f190403904)

> re.escape() now escapes only special characters.

Previous version:

```
_alphanum_str = frozenset("_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ01234567890")
_alphanum_bytes = frozenset(b"_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ01234567890")

def escape(pattern):
    if isinstance(pattern, str):
        alphanum = _alphanum_str
        s = list(pattern)
        for i, c in enumerate(pattern):
            if c not in alphanum:
                if c == "\000":
                    s[i] = "\\000"
                else:
                    s[i] = "\\" + c
        return "".join(s)
    else:
        alphanum = _alphanum_bytes
        s = []
        esc = ord(b"\\")
        for c in pattern:
            if c in alphanum:
                s.append(c)
            else:
                if c == 0:
                    s.extend(b"\\000")
                else:
                    s.append(esc)
                    s.append(c)
        return bytes(s)
```

It was modified on Apr 13 2017, so looking on [versions history](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Version_history) `re.escape('!') == '\\!'` should work on Python 3.6 and older versions.

Comment: So could you please explain why `assert re.escape('!') == "\\!"` works in a console?

Comment: Strange. It does for me. (Python 3.6.7 in Linux)

Comment: I edited the message, problem depends on the version of  python or pytest

Comment: OK, your answer is corrent (was correct also before the correction), is not a bug but a change of functionality.